# Retrieving string for if/else clause in android studio

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

I'm trying to get a qr code scanner going where it should redirect to different activities in dependancy on the code scanned but I'm having trouble getting the string from the result in the correct form.

```
  @Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan results");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    String id_helper = result.getText().toString();

    if (id_helper == "1") {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample1.class));
    } else if (id_helper == "2") {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample2.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample3.class));
    }
```

Comment: If I get what you are asking well, then you want to pass the QR code to your other classes, Sample1, Sample2 and Sample3?

Comment: Are you getting correct value of id_helper?

Comment: i want to be redirected to certain class based on what the qr code was, i dont need to pass the qr code itself to the activities

Comment: @Alpha that might be an issue, im fairly new to android/intellij and not really sure how to check, i had qr code that produced the string "1" but activity Sample3 started anyway so there might be an issue there

Comment: Yep, then check the answers. the three first are valid for your case.

Comment: And remember java can't check non primitive types via `==` or `>` etc.

Comment: If any of the answers gets you what you need, please accept and up vote if possible

Comment: thanks a lot guys, it works, i love you all <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing the string in wrong way, In Java you have to compare string using the `equals` method.

```
if ("1".equals(id_helper)) {
    // Open activity
}
```

Always put the known variable as on the left side of the condition to avoid `NullPoinerExceptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement to be like this:

```
if ("1".equals(id_helper)) {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample1.class));
} else if ("2".equals(id_helper)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample2.class));
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample3.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are doing invalid String checks.

```
if (id_helper == "1") {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample1.class));
    } else if (id_helper == "2") {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample2.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Sample3.class));
    }
```

your code uses `==` instead of `myString.contentEquals("2")` or `myString.equals("2")` or myString.equalsIgnoreCase("2")

Comment: ohh ok, too little too late :D